# Tic-Tac-Toe in C++

Tags: c++, tic-tac-toe, c++14

I created a program on Code::Blocks that allows you to play Tic-Tac-Toe with 2 players on the same program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

char square[10] = {'o','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};

int checkwin();
void board();

int main()
{
    int player = 1, i, choice;

    char mark;
    do {
        board();
        player = (player % 2) ? 1 : 2;

        cout << "Player " << player << ", enter a number: ";
        cin >> choice;

        mark=(player == 1) ? 'X' : 'O';
        if (choice == 1 && square[1] == '1') {
            square[1] = mark;
        } else if (choice == 2 && square[2] == '2') {
            square[2] = mark;
        } else if (choice == 3 && square[3] == '3') {
            square[3] = mark;
        } else if (choice == 4 && square[4] == '4') {
            square[4] = mark;
        } else if (choice == 5 && square[5] == '5') {
            square[5] = mark;
        } else if (choice == 6 && square[6] == '6') {
            square[6] = mark;
        } else if (choice == 7 && square[7] == '7') {
            square[7] = mark;
        } else if (choice == 8 && square[8] == '8') {
            square[8] = mark;
        } else if (choice == 9 && square[9] == '9') {
            square[9] = mark;
        } else {
            cout << "Invalid move ";
            player--;
            cin.ignore();
            cin.get();
        }
        i = checkwin();
        player++;
    } while(i == -1);
    board();
    if (i == 1) {
        cout << "Player " <<--player<< " win ";
    } else {
        cout << "Game draw";
    }
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}

int checkwin()
{
    if (square[1] == square[2] && square[2] == square[3]) {
        return 1;
    } else if (square[4] == square[5] && square[5] == square[6]) {
        return 1;
    } else if (square[7] == square[8] && square[8] == square[9]) {
        return 1;
    } else if (square[1] == square[4] && square[4] == square[7]) {
        return 1;
    } else if (square[2] == square[5] && square[5] == square[8]) {
        return 1;
    } else if (square[3] == square[6] && square[6] == square[9]) {
        return 1;
    } else if (square[1] == square[5] && square[5] == square[9]) {
        return 1;
    } else if (square[3] == square[5] && square[5] == square[7]) {
        return 1;
    } else if (square[1] != '1' && square[2] != '2' && square[3] != '3'&& square[4] != '4' && square[5] != '5' && square[6] != '6'&& square[7] != '7' && square[8] != '8' && square[9] != '9') {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

void board()
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "\tTic Tac Toe";

    cout << "Player 1 (X)  -  Player 2 (O)" << endl << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
    cout << "  " << square[1] << "  |  " << square[2] << "  |  " << square[3] << endl;

    cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
    cout << "     |     |     " << endl;

    cout << "  " << square[4] << "  |  " << square[5] << "  |  " << square[6] << endl;

    cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
    cout << "     |     |     " << endl;

    cout << "  " << square[7] << "  |  " << square[8] << "  |  " << square[9] << endl;

    cout << "     |     |     " << endl << endl;
}
```

I realize from past posts that `using namespace std` is considered bad practice, though I used it because adding all the `std::`(anything) would be very tedious. I also realized that there is probably an `if` statement overflow, so I'm wondering what can help.

Answer (score 3):

#### Counting starts at 0

Get used to the fact that in C and C++, counting starts at 0. You have a lot that starts at one, and leaves element 0 of arrays unused. That *can* be an acceptable strategy for handling things like porting existing Fortran code to C or C++, but it's Not how you want to write new code.

#### Meaningful Names

Rather than (for example) having `checkwin` return -1, 0, or 1 to indicate current status, I'd prefer to define an enumeration and return an instance of it:

```
enum { WON, DRAW, ONGOING };
```

At least to me, this makes client code like:

```
    i = checkwin();
    player++;
} while(i == ONGOING);
board();
if (i == WIN) {
    cout << "Player " <<--player<< " win ";
} else {
    cout << "Game draw";
}
```

... a lot more readable.

#### Verbosity

A lot of this strikes me as excessively verbose for what it accomplishes. Perhaps the most striking example would be your `checkwin`. Most of the code there can be reduced to a couple of simple loops with an array of indices into the main array:

```
int checkwin() {
    static const char index[][3] = {
        { 0, 1, 2 },
        { 3, 4, 5 },
        { 6, 7, 8 },
        { 0, 3, 6 },
        { 1, 4, 7 },
        { 2, 5, 8 },
        { 0, 4, 8 },
        { 2, 4, 6 }
    };

    for (auto const &s : index)
        if (square[s[0]] == square[s[1]] && square[s[1]] == square[s[2]])
            return WON;

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        if (square[i] == i + '0')
            return ONGOING;
    return DRAW;
}
```

#### Digits are Contiguous

C++ guarantees that the characters for '0' through '9' are contiguous, so instead of

```
    if (choice == 1 && square[1] == '1') {
        square[1] = mark;
    } else if (choice == 2 && square[2] == '2') {
        square[2] = mark;
    } else if (choice == 3 && square[3] == '3') {
        square[3] = mark;
    } else if (choice == 4 && square[4] == '4') {
        square[4] = mark;
    } else if (choice == 5 && square[5] == '5') {
        square[5] = mark;
    } else if (choice == 6 && square[6] == '6') {
        square[6] = mark;
    } else if (choice == 7 && square[7] == '7') {
        square[7] = mark;
    } else if (choice == 8 && square[8] == '8') {
        square[8] = mark;
    } else if (choice == 9 && square[9] == '9') {
        square[9] = mark;
```

...you can do something like:

```
if (square[choice] == choice + '0')
    square[choice] = mark;
```

Though you do need to assure that `choice` is in the correct range *before* doing this.

#### More and Simpler Functions

I think I'd take that chunk of code and turn it into a simple function to determine whether a particular square is already used:

```
bool square_used(int num) { 
    return square[num] != num + '0';
}
```

Then the code to take a move would look something like:

```
do {
    cout << "Player " << player << ", enter a number: ";
    cin >> choice;
} while (choice < 0 || choice > 9 || square_used(choice));
```

That, in turn, probably makes sense as a function in itself that only ever returns a valid move.

Once we've done that, the main loop compresses down to something like:

```
do { 
    auto choice = get_move(player);
    square[choice] = mark;
    status = checkwin();
    player ^= 1;
} while (status == ONGOING);

if (status == WON)
     std::cout << "Player : " << player << " Won!\n";
else
     std::cout << "Draw\n";
```